# What does the asterisk symbol on an erd attribute mean

Tags: database, ms-access, entity-relationship

I just found a database that has asterisk symbol on some of the attributes. I don't know what it means. Can you please help me?[image]

Comment: Asterisks don't normally appear on attributes, but rather on the association lines between entity sets and relationships. Is that what you meant? If not, a picture might help clarify the situation.

Comment: I added an image

Comment: Your image shows a table diagram, not an ER diagram, and in this case I suspect the asterisk means that a column doesn't allow nulls. The app's documentation may give more information.

Answer (score 0):

It means that that side of the relation can have an unlimited number of rows.